# csh: how to test for blank correctly?

Tags: csh

I want to test if a variable is totally empty in csh.

```
set R='dddd aaa'
if ( '${R}' ) then
    echo not empty

else
    echo 1111
endif
```

However it apparently does not work.

It gives this error message:

```
/usr/bin/test: argument expected
if: Expression Syntax.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
if ( "x$R" == "x" ) then
    echo empty
else
    echo not empty
endif
```

The C shell doesn't have an empty operator like bash.  Also, you can't quote with ' as it will prevent the variable expansion.

Comment: It works. Thanks. But for some reason, the "/usr/bin/test: argument expected" error message remains. Do you know why?

Comment: You probably have a superfluous bracket somewhere else in your script (they are a shorthand for /usr/bin/test)

Comment: Do "set echo" at the top of the script.  It's coming from somewhere else, I'm sure, because I ran the code above through csh and it didn't complain.